# react-native push notification azure

Tags: android, azure, react-native, push-notification

I want use push notification from azure notification hub in my react-native app (android app).

For push notification plugin in react-native i use https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification. 
I have done everything that is in instruction and local notification work fine on device.

But when I want use notification hub from azure nothing happens. I have registered my app in firebase, after that I've added Server key to notification hub in azure and use Sender ID for react-native app. Everything looks good, but when I want send test msg from azure I see *

> "Message was successfully sent, but there were no matching targets."

Can someone help me with this?

Thank you :)

Comment: Got the exact same problem. Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: unfortunately no, for now I've moved to appcenter

Comment: Hi did you get any solution?